# Django render_to_response() is returning empty response

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, django

I want to be able to return HTML response and append it to my DOM with AJAX but it is returning an empty response.

**AJAX**:

```
$(document).on('click', '.load-more-posts', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var userID = $('.user_id').val();
    var request = $.ajax({
          url: "/mysite/load_more/",
          type: "POST",
          data: { user_id : userID },
          dataType: "html"
        });
        request.done(function( msg ) {          
            console.log(msg);
        });
})
```

**urls.py**:

```
url(r'^load_more_posts/$', views.load_more, name='loadMore'),
```

**views.py**:

```
def load_more(request):
    if request.is_ajax():

        loaded_post = request.session['loaded']
        more_posts = Posts.objects.all()[loaded_post:5]
        request.session['loaded'] += 5
        context = {'more_posts':more-posts}

        return render_to_response('mysite/loadmore.html', context)
```

**loadmore.html**:

```
this is all I have in the html file

{% for article in more_posts %} 
    <div class='user-article'>
        <h3> {{article.header}} </h3>
        <p> {{article.content}}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

1. Why does this return empty response?
2. Do I need to put `<!DOCTYPE html>`, `<html lang="en">`, `<head>` in the html?
3. How do I `{% load staticfiles %}`

Comment: I don't know what staticfiles has to do with anything in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
more_posts = Posts.objects.all()[loaded_post:5]
```

won't work if `loaded_post` is greater than 5, since slicing a list [6:5] will return []. You presumably mean:

```
more_posts = Posts.objects.all()[loaded_post:loaded_post+5]
```

Comment: This did it. As expected.